# Creating vs adding primary (foreign) key constrants

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I wonder, is there any difference between these two ways of adding a foreign (or primary) key to a table?

```
--1
--a
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY(id);

--b
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_fk_user_id_to_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES "user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;

--2
--a 
CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)

--b
CREATE INDEX fk_my_table_fk_user_id_to_user
  ON my_table
  USING btree
  (user_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part A (PK)

There is no difference for the `PRIMARY KEY`, both statements create a `PRIMARY KEY`. There *is* a small difference between a `UNIQUE` constraint and a `PRIMARY KEY` in that the primary key is shown as such in system catalogs. Both can be targets of foreign keys, so it doesn't matter much. PostgreSQL doesn't even care whether a proper `UNIQUE` constraint exists or not, it just checks for an underlying `UNIQUE` index for the target of a foreign key.

So both (a)s are equivalent. For the purposes of foreign keys, so would a simple `UNIQUE` constraint, or a separate `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_table(my_table_pk)`, but you should always use the proper `PRIMARY KEY` definition to create a PK. Some tools need to know what the table's declared primary key is and look it up in the catalogs. Also, this might change in future.

### Part B (FK)

The second part (b) in example 2 doesn't add any kind of constraint at all. You're just creating an index on the column you store the foreign ID in. An actual `CONSTRAINT` is required to do anything, e.g. in the table definition you might write:

```
user_id integer REFERENCES "user"(id)
```

or, declaring the constraint separarely:

```
user_id integer,
CONSTRAINT some_fk_name FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
```

You may optionally index the foreign key column, which makes deletes/updates on the parent faster and can improve certain queries. The index on the foreign key doesn't have any role in enforcing the foreign key constraint though.

Comment: @Alex Yes, as you can verify with `\dt tablename` or by examining `information_schema` to see the table constraints.